# I am trying implement authentication using the jwt token using djangorest framework but am getting assertion error

Tags: django-rest-framework

AssertionError: 'LoginView' should either include a serializer_class attribute, or override the get_serializer_class() method

**Here is the code**
class LoginView(GenericAPIView):

```
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        auth_token = jwt.encode({'username': user.username}, settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        data = {'user': serializer.data, 'token': auth_token}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response({'detail': 'Invalid credential'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: Even if i change  serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        data = {'user': serializer.data, 'token': auth_token} to  serializer_class = UserSerializer(user)
        data = {'user': serializer_class.data, 'token': auth_token} still it doesn't work

Comment: It's `serializer_class = UserSerializer` just the class name, and the in `post` use `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)`. And actually that serializer should have `username` and `password`. So you better create a `UserLoginSerializer` with those fields.